# Laptop boots to white screen

Tags: boot, laptop

I own an XMG A522 laptop.

Was working fine until now, but now it cannot boot.
When I turn it on, I get a white screen (directly, there is no big XMG logo before) and I do not see any POST process, it just gets to that white screen and does nothing after that.

If I try to use the keyboard function keys to change LCD luminosity, it reacts and I can dim it or increase it, and when using the "LCD" function key, it turns the displays off or on so the machine does react to some things but won't boot, nor can I access BIOS or anything.

I tried running this with and without an external monitor hooked, result is the same.

What can I do?

I opened a ticket on the Support but nothing yet. Also, I cannot seem to find any manual to find if there are some tricks like removing battery and holding Power button or whatnot...

Comment: Try opening it up (i can provide instructions if required) and looking if the laptop/monitor connection is dodgy.

Comment: @JamieWilletts My bad, didn't read correctly.

Comment: @Bas No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is most often the cause of a loose or damaged connection between the LED screen and the motherboard. If you are able to connect to an external monitor, or if you hear the Windows chime on startup, then there is likely no serious damage to your motherboard. Make sure when connecting the monitor that you connect before turning the laptop on, and after a few minutes (when Windows should have booted) then you can even try pressing {WINDOWS KEY}+P (pressing P twice and then releasing all) to manually adjust the display state.

If all of this fails and you cannot hear or see anything - then you likely have motherboard damage and will need to have your mobo replaced.